# AVAudioRecorder recorded m4a won't play

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

I have recording application and it is working fine for m4a files. Now issue is only arise when I close application without stopping AVAudioRecorder.

Here is my code for record function:

```
- (IBAction)recordTapped:(id)sender {
        // Set the audio file
        NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                                   @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                                   nil];
        NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

        // Setup audio session
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

        // Define the recorder setting
        NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

        // Initiate and prepare the recorder
        recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
        recorder.delegate = self;
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [recorder prepareToRecord];

        [session setActive:YES error:nil];

        // Start recording
        [recorder record];
}
```

And this is my stop recorder function:

```
- (IBAction)stopTapped:(id)sender {
    [recorder stop];

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
}
```

So now when I start recording and after some recording, I tap on stop button and then try to play recording. It works fine.
Now if I start recording and then without stopping I double tap on home button and from app list I closes app. Then I restart app and try to play that previously recorded file, It won't work.

So is there any method to resolve this issue?